# mapping user defined data type (VBA) to C++

Tags: c++, vba, dll

Can somebody please tell me how to pass a VBA user defined type to a c++ (dll). I specially need to know how to handle string type of VBA in the dll.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Variable-length string members are passed as BSTR. Fixed-length string members are passed as arrays of CHAR containing ANSI strings.

There is an exhaustive sample in the Microsoft documentation [here](http://vb.mvps.org/tips/vb5dll.asp). This was originally written for VB5 but it also applies to VBA.